# Delete blank row and index column from dataframe which is not part of the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

[image]

This is my data frame. I need to remove the blank row beneath the column labels and the column with indexes 0 to 5. I tried .drop() and non of it works. I assume the issue comes from the MultiIndex, but I don't know how exactly.

This is my MultiIndex Code:

```
df_output = df_output.drop(labels='Target Completes', axis=1)
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
            ('', 'Country'),('','Completes'),('','Completes Share Achived'),('','Sample Share Used'),
            ('Age', '0-18 %'),('Age', '19-45 %'),('Age', '46-65 %'),('Age', '66+ %')

df_output.columns = cols
```

Comment: This seems to be Excel not a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Could you post your import code and the output of the dataframe print? It's easier to help you by looking how you import data.

Comment: df_output = df_output.drop(labels='Target Completes', axis=1)
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
            ('', 'Country'),('','Completes'),('','Completes Share Achived'),('','Sample Share Used'),
            ('Age', '0-18 %'),('Age', '19-45 %'),('Age', '46-65 %'),('Age', '66+ %')
           
df_output.columns = cols

Comment: This is my MultiIndex Code

Comment: This does not explain how your supposed DF as presented has the column headings A to I which is Excel-like.